# Pandas: Saving 'groupby' output to csv, details about column indices and datetime format lost

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to save the output of a groupby operation into a csv file through Pandas. My groupby operation is a combination of grouping by a variable 'ID' and summing the values, and then resampling these summed up values by a timeframe, for example, by week. The commands look like

```
tdGroupedWeek = (taxiData.groupby(['Taxi ID', pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Trip End Timestamp')])
         ['Trip Total']
         .sum()
         .unstack(fill_value=0))

tdGroupedWeek.to_csv('week.csv', sep='\t',  date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Before saving, the dataframe looks like this:

```
Trip End Timestamp  2013-01-06 00:00:00     2013-01-13 00:00:00     2013-01-20 00:00:00     2013-01-27 00:00:00     2013-02-03 00:00:00     2013-02-10 00:00:00     
Taxi ID                                                                                     
A                       0.0                     0.0                     0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00    
B                       0.0                     0.0                     0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00        
C                       0.0                     0.0                     0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00        
D                       0.0                     0.0                     1181.28                 458.46                  0.0                     687.57 
E                       0.0                     0.0                     0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00
```

But when I re-open this csv, the dataframe seems to lose that extra identifier that names the column indices as 'Trip End Timestamp', and I am also having trouble converting the column names into datetime objects again because they're converted to strings. Now, the dataframe looks like:

```
Taxi ID     2013-01-06 00:00:00     2013-01-13 00:00:00     2013-01-20 00:00:00     2013-01-27 00:00:00     2013-02-03 00:00:00     2013-02-10 00:00:00     
0   A                       0.0                     0.0                 0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00    
1   B                       0.0                     0.0                 0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00    
2   C                       0.0                     0.0                 0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00    
3   D                       0.0                     0.0                 1181.28                 458.46                  0.0                     687.57 
4   E                       0.0                     0.0                 0.00                    0.00                    0.0                     0.00
```

Is there a way to preserve that detail while writing the csv; or is there a way to

1. Convert certain column names to datetime objects?

Accessing specific indices as `df.columns[i]` and applying `to_datetime` doesn't work, as it returns "Index does not support mutable operations".

2. Rename the header row as "Trip End Timestamp" again?

Comment: read_csv or is it from_csv has a parse dates kwarg

Comment: `read_csv`'s `header` argument will take a list of rows that make up the multi-index.

Comment: But the details are actually lost during the `to_csv` operation, so isn't it a little more complicated to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question in the context of a csv, but saving the dataframe in hdf5 format actually preserves the multi-index as well as the datetime objects.